# Can't save both entities with one-to-one relationships in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I'm trying work with one to one mapping in Hibernate and I have got confused. I have two tables Student and Address mapping by one-to-one relationships and set foreign key for Address table. I have created a function save data to database, look like this :

```
public static void oneToOneMappingWithXML(Session session) throws Exception {
    StudentEntity tom = new StudentEntity();
    tom.setName("Tom");
    tom.setAge(10);
    tom.setClazz("5B");
    tom.setStudentId(1);

    AddressEntity tom_address = new AddressEntity();
    tom_address.setCity("New York");
    tom_address.setAddressId(1);

    tom.setAddressByStudentId(tom_address);
    //tom_address.setStudentByAddressId(tom); //#1
    session.save(tom);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

And this is my mapping :

```
<class name="com.model.xmlType.AddressEntity" table="ADDRESS" schema="CHINOOK">
    <id name="addressId">
        <column name="ADDRESS_ID" sql-type="number(10)" precision="10"/>
    </id>
    <property name="city">
        <column name="CITY" sql-type="nvarchar2(50)" length="50"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="studentByAddressId" class="com.model.xmlType.StudentEntity"/>
</class>


<class name="com.model.xmlType.StudentEntity" table="STUDENT" schema="CHINOOK">
    <id name="studentId">
        <column name="STUDENT_ID" sql-type="number(10)" precision="10"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name">
        <column name="NAME" sql-type="nvarchar2(50)" length="50"/>
    </property>
    <property name="age">
        <column name="AGE" sql-type="number(10)" precision="10"/>
    </property>
    <property name="clazz">
        <column name="CLASS" sql-type="nvarchar2(10)" length="10"/>
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="addressByStudentId" class="com.model.xmlType.AddressEntity" cascade="all"/>
```

Entity Class

Student :

```
public class StudentEntity {
    private Integer studentId;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String clazz;
    private AddressEntity addressByStudentId;

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
       return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
       this.age = age;
    } 

    public String getClazz() {
       return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(String clazz) {
       this.clazz = clazz;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

       StudentEntity that = (StudentEntity) o;

       if (studentId != null ? !studentId.equals(that.studentId) : that.studentId != null) return false;
       if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
       if (age != null ? !age.equals(that.age) : that.age != null) return false;
       if (clazz != null ? !clazz.equals(that.clazz) : that.clazz != null) return false;

       return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = studentId != null ? studentId.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (age != null ? age.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (clazz != null ? clazz.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public AddressEntity getAddressByStudentId() {
        return addressByStudentId;
    }

    public void setAddressByStudentId(AddressEntity addressByStudentId) {
       this.addressByStudentId = addressByStudentId;
    }
}
```

Address:

```
public class AddressEntity {
    private Integer addressId;
    private String city;
    private StudentEntity studentByAddressId;

    public Integer getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(Integer addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        AddressEntity that = (AddressEntity) o;

        if (addressId != null ? !addressId.equals(that.addressId) : that.addressId != null) return false;
        if (city != null ? !city.equals(that.city) : that.city != null)   return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = addressId != null ? addressId.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public StudentEntity getStudentByAddressId() {
        return studentByAddressId;
    }

    public void setStudentByAddressId(StudentEntity studentByAddressId) {
        this.studentByAddressId = studentByAddressId;
    }
}
```

It's work very well, both entities saved. But when line #1 is uncommented, only entity Student will save. The code look like :

```
public static void oneToOneMappingWithXML(Session session) throws Exception {
    StudentEntity tom = new StudentEntity();
    tom.setName("Tom");
    tom.setAge(10);
    tom.setClazz("5B");
    tom.setStudentId(1);

    AddressEntity tom_address = new AddressEntity();
    tom_address.setCity("New York");
    tom_address.setAddressId(1);

    tom.setAddressByStudentId(tom_address);
    tom_address.setStudentByAddressId(tom); //#1
    session.save(tom);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

I don't know why. So, Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Show us your entities, especially the annotations on the references.

Comment: Re-reading your question, it seems the problem must be in `setAddressByStudentId` and/or `setStudentByAddressId`. What do those methods do? Show us da codez!

Comment: And reading it again, I'm not sure what you mean by "when line #1 is uncommented". Dou you mean executing line "#1" *instead* of the line above it or in addition to it?

Comment: I have updated all Entity Classes . Can u help me ?

Comment: I think I got it. Using annotations, you should add a `mappedBy` parameter to one side of the `@OneToOne`. In XML, apparently `inverse="true"` is needed, see e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20723071/1015327

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Hibernate does not automagically make object references bi-directional when you set the reference on one side only. Hence, *you* must make sure that, on a bi-directional reference, *both* sides get set correctly before persisting.

Try to look at the entities not as records in a database but as objects. If object "tom" does not "know" he even has an address, and "tom" is requested to persist itself, how could "tom" persist his address?

(In fact, you *could* save "tom" without an address, then save an address referencing "tom"; then, if you'd re-load "tom", he'd suddenly have an address, because *in the database* it does not matter which direction a relation has. But you should not do that.)

Always initialize your bi-directional references properly on both sides and you should be good.

Comment: I have updated my mapping. I think we don't need to look at entity class because everything works well, I have done it following a tutorial on Internet. When I add line #1, I want to see what will happen and the problem is it can't save Address when line #1 was added :( . Link tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
session.save(tom_address);
session.save(tom);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

save address before saving student.

Comment: I don't think so. Because it's one-to-one relationships, I think we don't need to save both entities.