# Can you explain the reason for using inverse=“true” to cfproperty tag in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

Can you explain the reason for using `inverse="true"` & `cascade` attribute in `cfproperty` tag ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: They're for use with [ORM](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/user-guide.html?topic=/coldfusion/developing-applications/morehelp/coldfusion-orm.ug.js). The Adobe docs on cfproperty aren't great... check out [cfdocs.org](https://cfdocs.org/cfproperty) for a better description of `cascade`. Since CF uses Hibernate under the hood, usually you can also find general answers by searching for "Hibernate {somePropertyName}" or just "ORM {someProperty}", ex. [inverse=true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20723071/8895292).

Comment: Both of those have to do with ORM. Learn more about those to see how you would use the properties. [Association Updates: Owning Side and Inverse Side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) and [Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) to get you started.